# Is there a way to highlight the node in Memgraph

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I have two questions. First, is there a way to highlight the node in Memgraph from the `WHERE` clause so I can find it in the graph?

Abd second, is there some documentation on how to (for example) highlight the shortest path between two subreddit nodes?
Thankful for any (beginner-friendly) learning resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find that part of the documentation here:
https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/next/reference-guide/graph-algorithms

To answer your questions:
-> Is there a way to highlight the node from the where clause so I can find it in the graph?

With `match` clause you can pass the value your node needs to have, without a need for `WHERE` clause, you can see more details here:
https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/match
Something like this (for **movielens** dataset, users are rating movies):

```
MATCH (u:User{name:"Brett"})-[rel *bfs]->(m:Movie)
UNWIND rel as r
RETURN  u, r, m
```

-> There are sample codes in the documentation mentioned earlier, feel free to explore them for the usage of the shortest path.